# Can't run JavaFX 3D codes on my PC

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, 3d, directx

i've written sample 3D codes in java using javaFX and java reported that my directx version was outdated, it prompted me to install a later version. Here is the message

> Device "Mobile Intel(R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft
>   Corporation - WDDM 1.1)" (\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
>   WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update
>   your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302

I checked my directx dialog, everything is okay! Here are screenshots

[image: Directx dialog screenshot]

[image: Directx Panel reports okay]

And moreover, i have directX version 11! so i don't know why java(1.8) is complaining about me not having version 8??

This is a sample code i compiled already, but only showed my a blank window with a list of errors

```
//D3Shapes.java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.Cylinder;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class D3Shapes extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        // Create a Box
        Box box = new Box(100, 100, 100);
        box.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
        box.setTranslateX(150);
        box.setTranslateY(0);
        box.setTranslateZ(400);

        // Create a Sphere
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50, 20);
        sphere.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
        sphere.setTranslateX(300);
        sphere.setTranslateY(-5);
        sphere.setTranslateZ(400);

        // Create a Cylinder
        Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(40, 120, 5);
        cylinder.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
        cylinder.setTranslateX(500);
        cylinder.setTranslateY(-25);
        cylinder.setTranslateZ(600);

        // Create a Light
        PointLight light = new PointLight();
        light.setTranslateX(350);
        light.setTranslateY(100);
        light.setTranslateZ(300);

        // Create a Camera to view the 3D Shapes
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        camera.setTranslateX(100);
        camera.setTranslateY(-50);
        camera.setTranslateZ(300);

        // Add the Shapes and the Light to the Group
        Group root = new Group(box, sphere, cylinder, light);

        // Create a Scene with depth buffer enabled
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200, true);
        // Add the Camera to the Scene
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        // Add the Scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the Title of the Stage
        stage.setTitle("An Example with specified Draw Mode");
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

This is the output from jvm during program runtime

```
Device "Mobile Intel(R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:35 PM javafx.scene.paint.Material <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:35 PM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:35 PM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:35 PM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:35 PM javafx.scene.LightBase <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:36 PM javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:36 PM javafx.scene.Scene <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:36 PM javafx.scene.Scene$7 invalidated
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:36 PM javafx.scene.shape.Mesh <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:36 PM javafx.scene.shape.Mesh <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
Dec 10, 2017 1:15:36 PM javafx.scene.shape.Mesh <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
```

Any tangible help will be appreciated as i need the 3D feature to continue to work on a quite huge Engineering software. BTW, i've updated my Windows 7 Ultimate OS to service pack 2, and i run windows seldom updates. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try updating the driver?

Comment: The error said you need driver version >= 8.15.10.2302, yet you have 8.15.10.1749, which is a lower version... So sounds like you indeed need to update your driver.

Comment: thats interesting, i thought i had directx driver version 11 as shown in the first picture.
but then, i've tried updating from device manager but windows keeps saying i have the latest update.
am i missing something?

Comment: You need to upgrade your integrated graphics card as it's outdated. But looks like it's an integrated graphics card so you might want to look for alternatives aka discrete graphics card

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. i thought as much as to why the driver wont find updates, i'm guessing the current version is the recommended for my PC toshiba L300. i'll try and find a discrete graphics card to use. 
or perhaps you have any recommendations for me?

Comment: Your PC is equipped with very old processor. I would recommend buying a new machine or you might want to buy a new discrete graphics card that supports your system.